# Get 'unrecognized selector' when trying to add dictionary to nsMutableArray

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableArray that prints something like:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7a64f450>(
{
    user = "Mark";
    age = 21;
},
{
    user = "Bill";
    age = 43;
}...
```

I'm looping through it to add another key here:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [dic setValue:carString forKey:@"car"];
  for(int i = 0; i < [final count]; i++) {
   NSLog(@"final is %@",[final objectAtIndex:i]);
 [[final objectAtIndex:i] addEntriesFromDictionary:car];
```

When I print final 'i' get:

```
final is {
        user = "Mark";
        age = 21;
}
```

But when i try to add entries I get the error:
-[__NSDictionaryI addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b803330'

How can I add the dictionary so final is:
    final is {
            user = "Mark";
            age = 21;
            car = "Ford";
    }

I've tried using NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary. I'm not sure if changing NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary would work or if it's possible (haven't found a solution on SO yet).

Comment: The error message is saying that you're calling that method on an immutable dictionary. Presumably, [final objectAtIndex:i] is returning an immutable dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionaries stored in your `final` array are immutable.  You need to replace them with a mutable dictionary that contains the merged objects -

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:carString forKey:@"car"];
for(int i = 0; i < [final count]; i++) {
   NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict=[final[i] mutableCopy];
   [mutableDict addEntriesFromDictionary:car];
   final[i]=mutableDict;
}
```